# iOS:UIScrollView nest UITableView,how to refresh UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit

[image: Picture]

### Problem

1.refresh UIScrollView A by pull down tableView B. The problem is that since nested,sometimes scrollView A don't scroll but tableView B could when I pull down .

2.I also need UITableView to refresh when pull up

would anyone get some solutions for me? I am really struggled with this problem

Comment: Tableviews have default scrolling so there is no need of scrollview

Comment: you have disable scrolling of tableview only then back side uiscrollview will scroll..